# svg2psd using tcpdf, font color is changed after converting it into pdf

Tags: pdf, svg, tcpdf

I have svg file which has some text written into it. I am working with `tcpdf` to convert svg into pdf.

I used [this](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps) example for conversion. All working good but there is one issue, svg contains some fonts which has color, but after converting it into pdf, color will change. see this [image]

First image has different font color and second is after converting to pdf has different color. I am using [this](http://printhubpro.co.uk/images/export.svg) svg file for conversion.
What is the possible solution for svg2pdf conversion?

Comment: How is the colour of that text specified in the SVG?  Can you update your post with the `<text>` element from the SVG - or at least the `fill` attribute value?  I am thinking perhaps your SVG is using a colour value that tcpdf doesn't support - such as the new-to-CSS3 `rgba()`.

Comment: yes i figured that now. working on that. thanks for the answer @PaulLeBeau